# PHP: Getting "405 Not Allowed" Error when iterating through large csv files

Tags: php, ajax, csv, nginx, http-status-code-405

[image]

I'm getting the above error when writing a large( having more than 1500 lines) csv excel files to the server database by ajax. Uploading gets completed but when the file is written into the database this error is fired.

The system works flawless for smaller csv files(less than 1500 lines), so i don't think it's a Cross-domain (CORS) request issue.(I'm POSTing to the same domain).

Since this probably is an issue with the file size I tried setting

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

but didn't help.
I'm using a shared hosting server of Bluehost so cannot edit server config files.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171530/405-error-php-iterating-through-large-excel-spreadsheet) regarding this same issue but it cantained no answers.

Comment: i cant see why your getting an Apache header code iterating an csv.

Comment: @nogad Let me elaborate the system's process.

First the system upload the csv file the the server and this step works fine. Then it iterates through the lines of the uploaded file and document each record to the database in a loop. Here after writing about 1000 records, the above error get fired. When I check the database, only some records are written into database(usually around 1000 records).

Comment: once the file is uploaded, there should be no Apache involved

Comment: @nogad Well the file is being uploaded as it should(uploaded files are available in the server). Once it's being iterated through for recording only this error gets fired.